# Simple Loop getting stuck

Tags: plsql

I am trying to run this pl/sql code but apparently it is getting stuck in the loop. I think the logic is correct.

```
DECLARE
  v_num1    NUMBER := 1;
  v_num2    NUMBER := 1;
  v_total   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  WHILE v_num2 < 6 LOOP

    v_total := v_num1 + v_num2;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num1 || ' + ' ||  v_num2 || ' = ' || v_total);

    IF v_num2  = 5 THEN
        v_num2 := 1;
        v_num1 := v_num1 + 1;
    ELSE
        v_num2 := v_num2 + 1;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping WHILE v_num2 < 6 LOOP

but when v_num2 is 5, then you assign it 1

v_num2 := 1;

so it's never equalling 6 and hence will loop forever.

Comment: yeah, i am blinding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you keep resetting v_num2 to 1 every time it gets to 5, so v_num2 will always be less than 6 and the loop will run forever.

```
  IF v_num2  = 5 THEN
        v_num2 := 1;
        v_num1 := v_num1 + 1;
    ELSE
        v_num2 := v_num2 + 1;
    END IF;
```